# Boolean object visible in rendered image

Tags: rendering, modifiers, visibility

[image]

Having a problem that is really frustrating me. When I render an image, the two boxes that I used for making sinks with a Boolean modifiers are appearing in the picture. I have deleted those boxes long ago and double checked all the layers and they aren't there. Funny thing is render view works just fine.

Comment: I guess they are there somewhere... try selecting the "cut" object (I guess the top element) and look at (or show) its modifiers. If you can't solve, you  can share the file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question and post the provided link

Comment: oh my god I am an idiot, after playing around for hours i found out that they were actually hidden in object. I hid them instead of deleting them xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your object is visible in render, but not in viewport. In any case it should still exist in the *Outliner*.

Try to find objects hidden in viewport but not in render, they would look like this

[image]

Then you can hide them in rendering by clicking the little camera icon, or just delete them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide a "live" boolean operator object, say while moving it around or otherwise working on it, it's convenient to move it to a separate layer ('M' key or use the Relations panel pictured).

[image: Object layer can be assigned from this panel, multi selection is possible.]

You can control visibility of your boolean(s) by hide/showing the corresponding layer (shift-click layer buttons in header). When layer is hidden, it's hidden in all of 3D view, preview and final render.

Setting render (camera icon) property to false in the Outliner, on the other hand, will still show the object when using the render display/preview mode, which may be unintended and annoying since you lose the WYSIWYG aspect as your boolean result is obscured.